# Get CPU Peak FP Performance and Latency and Bandwith from DRAM and L1 Cache

Tags: performance, memory-management, hardware, cpu, cpu-architecture

I have an Intel Pentium Dual T3200 with the following spec (calculated with CPU-Z):

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/878621/specs.html

and the output of lshw:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/878621/lshw.html

How can i calculate the latency and bandwith (in cycles and in MB/s) of my main memory? and of my L1 cache?
I ran a benchamrk and l1 cache latency is 3 cycles. how can i find the rest?

What about the Peak FP Performance of my cpu?

Comment: If you want a tool for that it's a bit off topic, if you want to find out programmatically, just write a small linked list benchmark that is bigger than your 1M L2 but fits in your 1G mem, and measure the average latency. Peak BW is trickier, measure parallel consecutive accesses from both cores. Note that DRAM accesses can vary quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lmbench`, in particular the benchmarks `lat_mem_rd` and `bw_mem` i got everything i needed to calculate latency and bandwith..

Using `LINPACK` i calculated the Peak FP Performance with one of the tests inside!

Comment: CPU-Z cache latency tool uses exactly the same method as lat_mem_rd from lmbench. Theoretical peak of FP Performance should be computed by reading your CPU specifications, how much floating point additions and multiplications of needed format (ususally 64-bit ieee double, for GPUs often 32-bit float) can be finished in every cpu clock; then multiply by CPU frequency (and then by core count). For Intel usual FP per clock are 2 (64-bit) for P4 and Core; 4 for Core 2; 8 for earlier AVX CPUs (Sandy, Ivy);  16 for Haswell with AVX2; 16 for XeonPhi with AVX512.